# Is it possible to remotely read data from Sharepoint on prem server

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, webclient

Reading userprofile data from Sharepoint online is straightforward with CSOM. For example:

```
        string siteURL = @"https://foo.sharepoint.com";

        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteURL);

        var securePass = new SecureString();

        "password123".ToList().ForEach(s => securePass.AppendChar(s));

        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("userName", securePass);

        var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(ctx);
        var personProperties = peopleManager.GetMyProperties();

        ctx.Load(personProperties, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Is this possible to do to a Sharepoint 2013 on premise using `WebClient` or something similar?

Comment: CSOM is that "something similar" - it's **SharePoint's** client-side library, not SP Online's. Just pass the URL of the site. Have you tried this? Did you encounter a specific problem? If so, what is it? Did you check the MSDN examples?

Comment: Thanks for your input @PanagiotisKanavos, Only change needed is to use the `NetworkCredential` class instead of `SPOnlineCredentials`